# Recommendation for a virtual site-to-site VPN appliance

Tags: networking, openvpn, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn

can you please recommend an Virtual Appliance or Operating System for creating multiple site-to-site VPN?

The appliance must of course handle IPSec. It should also be OpenVPN capable. An Additional SSL VPN is a plus. It should run on normal virtualization servers like Xen and VMware. An easy to use Webinterface must be included. It is not required to be free but should start with very low pricing for small installations. Open Source solutions preferred.

Thanks!

P.S: Happy 100,000st question :)

Comment: Product and service recommendations are specifically off topic for ServerFault (see point 4 in the NOT About section of the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org) -- FreeBSD-based gateway/firewall/router distro does it all.  Can't say enough positive things about it.

Comment: Yes pfSense is my first but only idea. Maybe I missed some cool project in the past years.